# Datamapper validation with form validation - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using this datamapper http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu

problem is datamapper have validation methods similar with codeigniter form validation.but not as same.

An example, a model admins model validation array:

```
public $validation = array(
        'username' => array(
        'rules' => array('unique', 'required', 'trim', 'max_length' => 60, 'min_length' => 3),
        'label' => 'User'
    ),
        'password' => array(
        'rules' => array('required', 'trim', 'encrypt', 'min_length' => 6),
        'label' => 'Password'
    )
);
```

but form validation array must be like that:

```
public $form_validation = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'username',
        'label' => 'User',
        'rules' => 'unique|required|trim|max_length[60]|min_length[3]'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'password',
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rules' => 'required|trim|encrypt|min_length[6]'
    )
);
```

I don't want to make two manual validation for new admin adding (first form validation, after datamapper validation). I think there is a way to make this with just one manual validation.

sorry my bad English, I hope you understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Datamapper's validation alone should be enough, without the CI's form library.

When you try to save the model, the `save()` method will return a `true` or `false` depending on if the save was successful. If it isn't the model's [`error` property](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/validation.html#Error.Messages) should be filled with the error messages generated for the validation that failed. The messages can be loaded from [language files with keys named appropriately](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/validation.html#Custom.Error.Messages), also the codeigniter's form validation library's `form_validaton_lang.php` is loaded too.

In your controller you could make use of them like this:

```
Class TheController extends CI_Controller {
    function save() {
        // get the model object somehow
        // ...
        // update attributes
        $model->prop0 = $this->input->post('prop0');            
        $model->prop1 = $this->input->post('prop1');
        // try to save it
        if ($model->save()) {
            // save successful
            redirect(...);
        } else {
            // save failed load form again, with the model
            $this->load->view('path/to/the/form', array('model' => $model));
        }
    }
}
```

The view could work like this:

```
 <form method="post" action="...">

     <label>prop0</label>
     <input type="text" name="prop0" value="<?php print $model->prop0?> ">
     <?php if (!empty($model->error->prop0)):?> 
         <div class="error"><?php print $model->error->prop1; ?></div>
     <?php endif; ?>

     <label>prop1</label>
     <input type="text" name="prop1" value="<?php print $model->prop1?> ">
     <?php if (!empty($model->error->prop0)):?> 
         <div class="error"><?php print $model->error->prop1; ?></div>
     <?php endif; ?>

     <buton type="submit">go</button>
 </form>
```

The same form can be used when no previous model exists in the database, just create an empty instance of the model you need, and pass it to the form.